# WxPython: How to move Items in a sizer by showing and hiding items within it

Tags: wxpython

Ive managed to make a small example of what I would like to achieve. When I double click on the green panel, it dissapears which is what I want and when I double click on the red panel the green panel appears again which is also fine.
What I am having trouble with is how do I move the green panel up to take the place of the red panel when the red panel is not shown and remove the green panel back to how it was when the red panel appears, without having to change the position of them in the grid sizer.

Can someone please help?

Below is the template code which I am trying to achieve this:

```
import wx
class myframe(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        "Constructor. No arguments"
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, size=(2000,2000))
        self.myPanel1 = wx.Panel( self, size=(300, 300) )
        myPanel2 = wx.Panel( self, size=(300, 300) )

        self.myPanel1.SetBackgroundColour("green")
        myPanel2.SetBackgroundColour("red")
        myGridSizer = wx.GridBagSizer()
        myGridSizer.Add(self.myPanel1, pos=(0, 0), span=(1,1), flag=wx.EXPAND)
        myGridSizer.Add(myPanel2, pos=(1, 0), span=(1,1), flag=wx.EXPAND)
        self.SetSizer(myGridSizer)
        self.myPanel1.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_DCLICK, self.hideMe)
        myPanel2.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_DCLICK, self.showMe)

    def hideMe(self, event):
        print "hide!"
        self.myPanel1.Hide()

    def showMe(self, event):
        print "show!"
        self.myPanel1.Show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print "Running Demo"
    app = wx.App()
    region = myframe()
    region.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call self.Layout() after calling Hide and Show.
I've added 'myGridSizer.SetEmptyCellSize((0, 0))' to remove the gap at the top.

```
import wx
class myframe(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        "Constructor. No arguments"
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, size=(2000,2000))
        self.myPanel1 = wx.Panel( self, size=(300, 300) )
        myPanel2 = wx.Panel( self, size=(300, 300) )

        self.myPanel1.SetBackgroundColour("green")
        myPanel2.SetBackgroundColour("red")
        myGridSizer = wx.GridBagSizer()
        myGridSizer.Add(self.myPanel1, pos=(0, 0), span=(1,1), flag=wx.EXPAND)
        myGridSizer.Add(myPanel2, pos=(1, 0), span=(1,1), flag=wx.EXPAND)
        self.SetSizer(myGridSizer)
        self.myPanel1.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_DCLICK, self.hideMe)
        myPanel2.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_DCLICK, self.showMe)
        myGridSizer.SetEmptyCellSize((0, 0))

    def hideMe(self, event):
        print "hide!"
        self.myPanel1.Hide()
        self.Layout()

    def showMe(self, event):
        print "show!"
        self.myPanel1.Show()
        self.Layout()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print "Running Demo"
    app = wx.App()
    region = myframe()
    region.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Thanks Yoriz, it seems that by adding the SetEmptyCellSize, that small grey border at the top disappears. :)

Comment: Note: Seems like the approach with the SetEmptyCell is only valid for grid sizers and not for all sizers which is okay in my case but may need a different approach if using another sizer.

Comment: If you where to use a Boxsizer it works fine as it is, there is no grey border left behind, i think SetEmptyCellSize is specific to when using a GridBagSizer only.

Answer (score 1):

Technically, you can't make it work this way without actually moving the widgets. In Yoriz's example, it almost puts the Red panel where the Green one was, but you'll notice that there is a gray strip separating the Red panel from the top of the frame. That is because the grid sizer is still reserving space for the hidden Green panel.

If you want it to be seamless, you would want to look at the Detach() and the various Insert() methods of the sizer: http://wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.Sizer-class.html

Comment: Added this line and the reserved space goes away myGridSizer.SetEmptyCellSize((0, 0))

Comment: Detach and Insert seem to be another valid way of performing this, however I would have to keep some sort of list of the widgets and their corresponding positions so that I can detach and re-insert them into the right positions.